# Threading in Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm trying to use threading in Flask, but unfortunately I don't get any result.

This is the Flask app code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session
import os
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(2)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():

    def multiply(x,y):
        session['result'] = x*y

    t = threading.Thread(target=multiply, args=(4,5))
    t.start()

    return render_template('index.html')
```

And when I go to the index page and print the result in the session, I get nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?   You most likely expect something from the thread to get rendered, but in this case your function probably returns before your thread has managed to start. Does it work as expected if you add t.join() after t.start()?

Comment: Generally, using threading in a web app is a bad idea. Use a separate offline process manager, eg Celery.

Comment: @Hanuu I tried join() but nothing changed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I will consider this, thank you.